# Creating a new web forms project in Alfresco 4.0 Community Edition using Web Quick Start

Tags: web, content-management-system, alfresco

I want to create a Web project using Alfresco 4.0.

Alfresco Developer Guide -Jeff Potts Book guides me to create a web project using Alfresco 3.x. It uses the Alfresco WCM component. But I can't find the WCM component for Alfresco 4.x (Check this link [Alfresco Download](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_4.0.b)  )

Instead of WCM component I can find the  Web Quick Start component. Is it possible to create a web project using Web Quick Start alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webforms and the whole AVM are outdated technology. WCM Quickstart is a just a sample implementation for web content management and has nothing in common with the AVM based approach in 3.x. It may cover very basic use cases, but I would generally discourage people from using it unless they are very clear about their requirements and what's covered by Quickstart.

That said, the best resources besides source is at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Installation_and_Configuration and http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Developer_Guide. Follow them and you get FormService based forms for the various content types.